JS code execution upon a press of an HTML input button
I have a laravel project with create.blade.php file:
<input id="testButton" type="submit" value="test"/>

and a javascript api.js file:
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("testButton").click(function(){
        alert("button pressed"):
    });
});

How do i make a button from HTML execute the JS code?
So far i have tried replacing JS code with this:
$("testButton").click(function(){
    alert("button pressed");
});

or this:
$(document).on("click","testButton",function(){
    alert("button pressed");
});

but it did nothing.
Replacing <input> to <button> and changing type= from submit to button also did nothing.

$("testButton") is a selector for an HTML element called testButton. $("#testButton") would be a selector for an HTML element with the ID testButton. Also, how is this problem related to PHP or Laravel?

Are you using jquery? If so, you may get more relevant answers by adding that as a tag to the question and/or mentioning it in the question itself.

It seems that, you have to tell the button to run which function when onClick event fires.
I have tested the below and seems working fine, where "myTestScript.js" in the "head" section is loaded first, and the function "display()" in the JS file is triggered when the button is clicked.


function display() {
            alert("button pressed");
         }
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="google" content="notranslate"/>
    <script src="myTestScript.js"></script>
 </head>

 <body translate="no">
    <input id="testButton" type="submit" value="test" onClick="display()"/>
 </body>
</html>



